# error in setting up django with mod_wsgi

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to set up django with mod_wsgi (on apache). Its giving this error:

Attempt to serve directory: /home/mysite/products/templates/

httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/home/mysite"

<Location "/">
    SetHandler python-program
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
    PythonPath "['/home/','/home/mysite/'] + sys.path"
    PythonDebug Off
</Location>
```

django.wsgi (placed in the folder /home/mysite/public_wsgi):

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

path = '/home/mysite/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

Virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /home/mysite/products/templates

WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi /home/mysite/public_wsgi

Alias /static/ /home/mysite/products/static/
Alias /robots.txt /home/mysite/products/templates/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /home/mysite/products/static/images/favicon.ico
<Directory /home/mysite/products/static>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>    

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes
    DirectoryIndex /home/mysite/products/templates/home.html
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Can't seem to figure out the problem. How can i resolve this error? Any help on this would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use mod_python and mod_wsgi at the same time. This will cause various conflicts and problems. You should remove the mod_python setup and start over.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was moving from mod_python to mod-wsgi, hence the confusion, it works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

You should include /home/ in sys.path as well